# Every new Item added displays the same Date-Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

I did a todo app (beginner here) and I add a time whenever I add some todo. Heres what I did:

```js
const [date, setDate] = React.useState(Date());
```

Then every time I add a todo, Im setting the state to current time that I push that todo:

```js
const addTodo = (id, title, completed) => {
  const newTodo = { id, title, completed }
  setTodos([...])
  setDate(new Date().getSeconds())
}
```

I used getSeconds to easily know the time. Heres the thing, when I add a todo, it show the seconds (for example 1 second), when I add another todo after 1 second, its shows 2. But the prev todo that has a 1 second has been overriden by the current todo so they both have 2 and so on.. hope you get my problem. What method should I use to become not synchronously changing, for ex: when I add a new todo at 2:00, then I add a new todo at 3:00

Comment: Can't understand your question. Btw if it is that all todos are showing same date, it's because you aren't saving the timestamp with each todo and using a global state which updates itself with the last todo created.

Comment: Im having a hard time in english coz thats not my native language, sry and yup, all todos are showing same date. For example I add a new todo at 3:00 then I add a new Todo at 4:00, the result is both time are now 4:00. Btw, whats the keyword for that? So I can search it. This is only my knowledge im a fully beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove this single date state manager.

```
const [date, setDate] = React.useState(Date());
```

and add each date instance inside the `newTodo` like

```
const addTodo = (id,title,completed) => {
 const newTodo = {id,title,completed, date: new Date()}
 setTodos([...todos, newTodo])
}
```

Comment: This idea looks good i'll try this. I'll update u if this works. Thanks man!

Comment: Dude you are awesome! Wish someday I can be good as you. This works dude.                                                                            
 I add get hours, min and sec to be able to run that and I concat them using colon. 
 const newTodo = {id,title,completed, date: new Date().getHours()+':'+new date().getMinutes()